# Why does coercing this factor variable from the documentation for factor variables return several NAs?

Tags: r, categorical-data

The documentation for factors gives this code as its first example of constructing a factor variable:

```
(ff <- factor(substring("statistics", 1:10, 1:10), levels = letters))
```

Said documentation suggests the following:

> To transform a factor `f` to approximately its original numeric values, `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` is recommended and slightly more efficient than `as.numeric(as.character(f))`.

But when I try those on their example, I get nonsense:

```
> (ff <- factor(substring("statistics", 1:10, 1:10), levels = letters))
 [1] s t a t i s t i c s
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
> ff
 [1] s t a t i s t i c s
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
> as.numeric(levels(ff))[ff]
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> as.numeric(as.character(ff))
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Where is my misunderstanding? I see nothing abnormal about the `ff` factor variable. It definitely has underlying numbers:

```
> as.integer(ff)
 [1] 19 20  1 20  9 19 20  9  3 19
```

and although its levels are characters, I don't see anything strange about that either - factor variables always have levels that are characters.

Comment: You want to extract the corresponding integer values here?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR No. I only want to know why the code that I used returns nonsense. I don't have any intended output.

Comment: The documentation refers to the "original _numeric_ values". Your original values are of class _character_, and `as.numeric("a-character")` returns `NA`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you created ff run this: `table(ff)`, It will tell you frequency of each alphabet even those which are not present there, the frequency for those are correspondingly 0.

Now `levels(ff)` returns all of these alphabets as character, wrapping them inside `as.numeric(levels(ff))` will  always return NA. The same goes with `as.numeric(as.character(ff))`.

My guess is that you may be confused between `labels` and `levels`. If you run `labels(ff)` then you will get numbers 1 to 10 quoted. If you convert using `as.numeric()`. You will get your results as 10 numbers. Run: `as.numeric(labels(ff))`

I hope this explains what you are confused about. please let me know otherwise.

output :

```
R>table(ff)
ff
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r 
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
s t u v w x y z 
3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 

R>levels(ff)
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h"
 [9] "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p"
[17] "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x"
[25] "y" "z"

R>labels(ff)
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6" 
 [7] "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
```

**EDIT:**

Okay, It seems OP is having issue with this line in documentation:

> The interpretation of a factor depends on both the codes and the
> "levels" attribute. Be careful only to compare factors with the same
> set of levels (in the same order). In particular, as.numeric applied
> to a factor is meaningless, and may happen by implicit coercion. To
> transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values,
> as.numeric(levels(f))[f] is recommended and slightly more efficient
> than as.numeric(as.character(f)).

Now the above says that if you have factors(originally as numbers), don't convert them into numbers directly for example:

```
nums <- c(1, 2, 3, 10)
new_fact <- as.factor(nums)
```

Now, if we try to get numbers from new_fact and run `as.numeric(new_fact)` we will get 1,2,3,4 (wrong)!!! Now that is wrong, so all the documentation is saying is to convert to original numbers, one has to perform `as.numeric(as.character(new_fact))` or `as.numeric(levels(new_fact))[new_fact]`, Both of which will return `1 2 3 10`. I hope this helps

Comment: I think there must have been a mistake with the documentation, since the code suggested their for extracting the original numeric values of a factor only returns `NA`.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR IMHO, Never ever the R documentation is wrong I have seen in my life. He is misinterpreted if you look closely he is calling `f` every where not `ff`. There seems to be some source of confusion at his end I believe, In the doc it says : (f. <- factor(ff)),

Comment: You are right, I tried it with `f <- factor(letters[1:20], labels = "letter")` & `as.numeric(labels(f))[f]` as you suggested and it gave me `[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20`. Thank you for your clarifications dear PKumar.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Yes, My Pleasure, Its common source of confusion for most of us.

Comment: Exactly but only in these kinds of situations that we learn a great deal.

Comment: @PKumar No, it doesn't. The line that you're referring to uses `f.` not `f`. I believe that you get the same results with `f.` as you do `ff`.

Comment: @J.Mini, but f is defined as factor(ff) , which is completely different object. I hope I am able to convey it properly, so essentially f is `factor(factor(...))`, so I believe that is why it might have bugged you

Comment: @PKumar There is no variable called `f` in the example code. The example code uses `ff` and `f.`.

Comment: @J.Mini, I have edited the post Please read the Edit and see if its fine. I hope this helps. All the best